# How to disable warnings for unused imports in Java in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, lint

I'm using the standard extension "Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat". How can I disable warnings for unused imports for Java projects in Visual Studio Code?

Maybe someone knows this and can help, because despite some extensive Google searches I can't find sufficient information on this. For other languages yes, but not for Java.

Comment: The easiest way to get rid of that warning is by removing any _unused_ import statement.

Comment: I don't know about VSCode but in IntelliJ/AndroidStudio and Eclipse it's one combination of keystroke will remove unused imports. I use VSCode for Golang and at every save, all unused imports are removed.

Comment: @RoslanAmir Automatic removal does not happen in VSCode. At least not by default. And I'm not aware of such a functionality: Would be great if it existed, so if someone knows about such kind of features, please tell. I couldn't find anything like that in the documentation of the VSCode extension.

Comment: @RegisMay - See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73104111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. It seems that you need to configure this on project level.

For ignoring all unused imports edit the file `.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` and add the following line:

`org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unusedImport=ignore`

Answer (score 1):

It could have been the VSCode setting. Go to the
.vscode -> settings.json
and set;

```
{
    "java.compile.nullAnalysis.mode": "disabled"
}
```

Comment: VSCode says "Specify how to enable the annotation-based null analysis" with automatic|interactive|disabled is not really helpful. Is there any kind of documentation on the feature you named? I can't find any.