# VSCode Java linting - disable specific warnings

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-studio-code

I'm using the [Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java) extension in VS Code (notably not the other extensions in the Java extension pack, as they aren't relevant for what I'm doing).

The linter is largely helpful, but it also highlights many issues that I want to ignore. For example, I don't want it to warn me about either of these:

> The declared package "" does not match the expected package ...

> ... is a non-project file, only syntax errors are reported

Every time I encounter warnings I want to ignore, I have to Google them and try to find the eclipse preference for that specific error. This is time consuming and not always possible (I haven't yet found out how to disable either of the above messages).

I've created a preferences file following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69871531/how-to-disable-warnings-for-unused-imports-in-java-in-visual-studio-code) that disables warnings like unused imports.

```
project_directory
├── .settings
│   └── org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
└── other_stuff
```

Often, as in the aforementioned question, I find lines like `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unusedImport=ignore`.

Where do people find these preference ids? I found a partial list [here](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ls/issues/581#issuecomment-373804678), but it doesn't have any documentation.

Given an arbitrary error message, like the ones above, how do I know which preference will disable it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `"java.errors.incompleteClasspath.severity"` setting in VS Code, set it to `"ignore"` to ignore errors.

```json
    "java.errors.incompleteClasspath.severity":"ignore",
```

Comment: This resolves that message, but it's the same general issue. I don't want to have to Google every warning message to find the proper id that needs to be changed in VS Code, because that doesn't always work. Are these warnings documented somewhere so I can search for the message and find the setting that needs to be changed? How did you know that was the right setting?

Comment: Check out your problem panel for detailed error messages and sources.